# How to use ngTable pagination with Firebase Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, firebase, ngtable

I am trying to use ngTable to organize my array information into a table. I know that doing the length of $scope.laundryData will return 0 so I made a variable ($scope.arrayLength) that keeps track of the length of the array from Firebase. The problem is that the table displays fine with the pagination buttons, but it doesn't do pagination. If I select the 10 pagination button, it still shows 13 items (all of the items in the list). I got the $scope.tableParams from the [ngTable website](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/1-1).

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name laundrytrackerApp.controller:ReportsCtrl
 * @description
 * # ReportsCtrl
 * Controller of the laundrytrackerApp
 */
angular.module('laundrytrackerApp')
  .controller('ReportsCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, ngTableParams) {
    var ref = new Firebase("firebase url");
    $scope.laundryData= $firebaseArray(ref);
    //console.log($scope.laundryData.length);

    $scope.laundryData.$loaded().then(function(laundryData) {
        console.log(laundryData.length); // data is loaded here
        $scope.arrayLength = laundryData.length;
    });

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: $scope.arrayLength, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve($scope.laundryData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    })
  });
```

Here's the view:

```
<div class="containter text-center">
  <div class="row header">
    <h2>Spending Reports</h1>
  </div>
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="laundry in laundryData | orderBy:'-$id'">
                    <td data-title="'Date'">{{laundry.date}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'User'">{{laundry.user}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Loads'">{{laundry.loads || '-'}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Refill'">{{(laundry.refill | currency) || '-'}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Cost'">{{(laundry.cost | currency) || '-'}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Balance'">{{(laundry.balance | currency) || '-'}}</td>
                </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try repeating over `$data` instead of `$scope.laundryData`:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="laundry in $data | orderBy:'-$id'">
    <td data-title="'Date'">{{laundry.date}}</td>
    <td data-title="'User'">{{laundry.user}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Loads'">{{laundry.loads || '-'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Refill'">{{(laundry.refill | currency) || '-'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Cost'">{{(laundry.cost | currency) || '-'}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Balance'">{{(laundry.balance | currency) || '-'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I believe `$data` is used internally by `ngTable` to keep track of the paginated array.